# Disable X11 windowing resizing but still receive the Configure events

Tags: linux, x11

I want my application to handle resizes on its own. Is there a way to stop the window manager from resizing my window during a resize event but still receive those events. EG: The window manager tells the window what the dimensions should but it is up to my application to actually perform the resize. I want resizing to behave more like wayland where it is the client who is responsible for the window.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not get configure notification events when there is no configuration change to your window.

If you want to do this you will need to draw your own size grips and listen for button click and/or drag events and write code to resize your window from there.